# update existing csv file with updated info in another csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have 2 csv files,

- File `zulu` has the base info, divided in columns.
- File `bommel` has only updated info with the same records in the same columns.

I want to solve this in Python (using the `csv` module from the standard library) without Pandas or other external resources.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

# Define column names
fields = ['capcode', 'discipline', 'region', 'location', 'description', 'remark']

# Open the neccesary files
with open('bommel_db_capcodes.txt', 'r') as readFile_bommel:
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as results:
            with open('zulu_db_capcodes.txt', 'r') as readFile_zulu:
                master = csv.DictReader(readFile_zulu, fieldnames=fields)
                update = csv.DictReader(readFile_bommel, fieldnames=fields)
                writer = csv.DictWriter(results, fieldnames=fields)

                # Saves and skips header to output file
                writer.writerow(next(master))

                # Goes through whole zulu csv
                for row in master:
                    for row2 in update:
                        if row['capcode'] in update:
                            writer.writerow(row2)
                        else:
                            writer.writerow(row)

ReadFilezulu.close()
ReadFilebommel.close()
results.close()
```

**Contents of `zulu` csv:**

```
capcode,discipline,region,location,description,remark
000400001,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water (Noord)
000400002,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,,
000400003,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water) (Oost)
000100000,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Aalsmeer,Postalarm
000100001,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,
000100002,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,Banaanzulu
000100003,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,
```

**Contents of `bommel` csv:**

```
capcode,discipline,region,location,description,remark
000100000,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,banaanProefalarm,
000100001,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Aalsmeer,Bevelvoerders,
000100004,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Aalsmeer,Korpsalarm,
```

**Current result**

```
capcode,discipline,region,location,description,remark
000400001,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water (Noord)
000400001,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water (Noord)
000400001,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water (Noord)
```

**Expected result**

```
capcode,discipline,region,location,description,remark                                            < from saving header
000400001,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water (Noord)     < from zulu
000400002,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,,                                                        < from zulu
000400003,Brandweer,Groningen,Groningen,Regionaal,Pelotonscommandant Logistiek/Water) (Oost)     < from zulu
000100000,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,banaanProefalarm,                                      < from bommel
000100001,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Aalsmeer,Bevelvoerders,                                 < from bommel
000100002,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,Banaanzulu                        < from zulu
000100003,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Amsterdam-Amstelland,,                                  < from zulu
000100004,Brandweer,Amsterdam-Amstelland,Aalsmeer,Korpsalarm,                                    < from bommel
```

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: Do you need rows to be ordered in a specific ways?  If so, how?

Comment: No, sorting is not an requirement, (can be handy, on the field capcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time when you use the condition `in update` you consume the entire input file. Because `update` is basically a generator, you exhaust it when you loop over it.

Also, your condition checks if *exactly* the same line exists in the update file, which of course it doesn't (you would not want or need to update anything if the data was exactly the same).

You want to read the update lines into memory once, then skip those lines from the master file when you see a line with the same key (not the whole line!)

I assume the first field (`capcode`) is the key here, though there could be other arrangements.

Tangentially, you can combine all the `with` statements; and when you use `with open`, there is no need to `.close()` anything.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv


fields = ['capcode', 'discipline', 'region', 'location', 'description', 'remark']

with open('bommel_db_capcodes.txt', 'r') as readFile_bommel, \
        open('results.csv', 'w') as results, \
        open('zulu_db_capcodes.txt', 'r') as readFile_zulu:

    master = csv.DictReader(readFile_zulu, fieldnames=fields)
    update = csv.DictReader(readFile_bommel, fieldnames=fields)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(results, fieldnames=fields)

    # Save header to output file and skip
    writer.writerow(next(master))

    # Skip header from updates
    next(update)

    # Read, remember, and write updated lines
    seen = set()
    for row in update:
        writer.writerow(row)
        seen.add(row['capcode'])

    for row in master:
        if row['capcode'] not in seen:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/7Aj1PQ

Comment: The open statement combined comes with an error on the comma after bommel :-s 
```    with open('bommel_db_capcodes.txt', 'r') as readFile_bommel,
                                                               ^
```
When I use your solution after opening the files on my way, it works like a charm..
I did use the wrong approach thinking it was with the `in` statement. I thought it would check te file and stop at the row that has the matching code...

Comment: Like the demo shows, the code works, though I was missing the backslash on that line in my first version; did you refresh the page before copying the code?

Comment: No, I did not see the \ version (yet).
Changed it, works like a charm!

Very helpfull, thank you!!